# How do I correct this subversion conflict, tree problem?

Tags: svn, merge-conflict-resolution

I have some subversion source I have been working on.

When I try to checkin I get the following error.

matth@blaze:~/dev/myproj$ svn commit
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Aborting commit: '/home/matth/dev/myproj/client' remains in conflict

In actual fact, client is missing.  That's ok, I don't need it under linux.
Suprised it's saying there is a conflict with it though.

Tried doing an update but it shows nothing. How do I remove the conflict and update client to check it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

svn st will probably show either a 'C' or an '!' for the 'client' directory, you either need to check out the 'client' directory, or use a subdirectory for the commit to make it not look in the 'client' directory for content.

oops, missed the fact that you already have a conflict in 'client'.

Quick solution:

```
rm -rf client
svn revert -R client
svn up client
```

Generally works when I encounter these situations. This assumes that there are no changes in client that you want to keep.

did you not check out client to begin with?

Comment: Thought I had checked out the client.  I wasn't bothered with it because it's windows only and I'm building the other components under linux.  Maybe you might have an answer for my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427834/can-run-update-and-it-works-but-commit-says-illegal-repository-url