# Can run update and it works, but commit says illegal repository url ''?

Tags: linux, svn, command-line

In subversion I'm trying to commit a project but running into an issue.

The error I get is

Illegal repository URL ''

How come I can run update, but commit on the same tree shows that?

Comment: What is the output of "svn info"?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly because the repository URL is on the public internet but private... but it is showing a valid URL.  It seems that others have had this problem before.  I suspect something has gotten corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hunting around it seems that a few other people have experienced some sort of local corruption at the top level their checked out project directory which is where I was committing from.

I followed the same procedure that was used to solve those cases which is to back up the sources.  Check out the project again.  Finally copy the changed files back over the freshly checked out copy.  Check it builds correctly.  And then commit that.

It seemed to solve it for me.

Comment: ugh, I'm having this problem but my current set of changes includes moves, renames, and deletions... "copying the changed files" is going to be a serious pita.

Comment: @qes: I realise your comment is 3 years old, but in case others are affected by this: updating the URL using Subversion->Working copy->Switch repository worked for me, and was far less tedious than deleting / downloading / copying.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it worked for me:

1. Create a folder.
2. Right button over folder and create repo here.
3. When pop up appears select create folder structure and then open folder.
4. When repository browser appears you see tags branch etc, right button again and create folder but now with tool `tortoise`.
5. Update you file to folder.